# jquery $.post not successful without return parameter

Tags: jquery

really strange. I do a call to the server for removing a value from database. Anyway, it works as expected, but if I do not send any data back, the function does not alert.

This works, if I do a echo (for example in php), otherwise it does not:

```
     $.post('api/finder/user.php', { search_id: $(btnobj).prop('id') }, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }, "json");
```

I do not want to echo anything back. Just run the script on the server side. Leaving funtion(data) as function().

EDIT

With .fail() it alerts within, instead of alert(1).

```
  $.post('api/finder/user.php', { search_id: $(btnobj).prop('id') },  function() {                      
                    alert(1);

                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                });
```

Comment: instead of return, print the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is `echo`ed in the PHP script is the value that is returned to the JavaScript. You should be making your PHP script print/return something, even if it is just:

```
echo json_encode(true);
```

It is important to have a valid JSON response given by the PHP if that's what the JavaScript is expecting!

### Code example (using `done()` and `fail()`):

```
$.post('api/finder/user.php', { search_id: $(btnobj).prop('id') })
    .done(function() {                      
        alert(1);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

### Check for server errors:

If the code keeps executing the code inside `fail()`, you need to check the response that is being given by the server for the AJAX request.

You can use the "Network" tab of the "Developer Tools" in Chrome to view the requests (AJAX POST request) and the responses as you are running your code. Check the "Status" of the response - it should be a 200 code (indicating success).

Comment: I know I added the "json" part, but I thought it was needed with the {} for parameters. Its not necessary needed.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what format you're returning the data in, the JavaScript code is still expecting something to be returned to it. If you don't really want data to be returned from the PHP, you would just return a `true` value on success and `false` on failure - this allows your PHP code to signal success/failure to the JS code.

Comment: I added a bit that might help you with the extra issues mentioned in your question edit.

Comment: No problem, hope the issue's sorted now!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you request `json` and don't return anything , there is no json to parse which will therefore trigger a parse error which you would see if you added an error handler.

A json parse error will mean your success callback will not fire and you won't see your alert. Don't request json if you don't expect json to be returned.

Remove the `dataType` argument and you should see alert regardless of returning data or not. Why you wouldn't want to return data however is unusual

Comment: Ok I think I found the error for the json, in my php I have: header('Content-Type: application/json'); So it will always trigger an error if I do not return anything. Could this be it?

Comment: yes.. exactly, you are telling it on both ends to expect json and not returning any

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is what your looking for?

```
$.post('api/finder/user.php', { search_id: $(btnobj).prop('id') });
```

If I mis-understood and you are actually looking for a way to return the data from within function(data) (a common question asked) then do this

```
function removeUser() {
    return $.post('api/finder/user.php', {
        search_id: $(btnobj).prop('id')
    }, null, "json");
};
```

then call using: (This will call even if you don't echo anything)

```
removeUser().done(function(data) {
    //parse 'data' response
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed it and now returning some data, I actually didn't manage to get it work without a return parameter. What I mean is, it did not alert. Instead it goes down to .fail(), if you see my updated question.